# Macro for setting print area not working

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a simple macro which will set a print area from selected area but i still get an error "Subscript out of range"

Here's the code

```
Worksheets("Zeszyt11").Activate ActiveSheet("Arkusz1").PageSetup.PrintArea = _ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Address
```

**EDIT**

Ok,i've got one more question: I would like to make a print area only out of cells i've selected,now it takes every with any text..How to fix it ?

Comment: Try deleting the `_` before `ActiveCell`

Comment: It says syntax error

Comment: @Atomix Well please [edit] your question and be very specific about line breaks in your code! Line breaks matter a lot in VBA. Make sure the line breaks in your question are the same as in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't say ActiveSheet("SheetName") try

```
Worksheets("Arkusz1").PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Address
```

Comment: It still says "Subscript out of range", i would like to attach this code into button if it matters

Comment: Does the sheet exist? Arkusz1  and is it in the currently active workbook? And is there any white space in the tab name?

Comment: Yes,name of my excel document is "Zeszyt11" and active workbook is "Arkusz1"

Comment: But you are referring by sheet name. So what is the name of the sheet you are trying to set the print area in?

Comment: @Atomix well a "excel document" does not exists. Be very specific how you name things. An Excel file is also called a workbook and it can contain many worksheets. So make sure you use the correct terms.

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out ! I've changed Zeszyt11 into Arkusz1 (sheetname) and it works ! Thank you guys !

Comment: @Atomix Please mark the answer as solution then. So everyone sees that this is solved.

Comment: Ok,i've got one more question: i would like to make a print area only out of cells i've selected,now it takes every with any text..How to fix it ?

Comment: Is this a **new** question ? :-)

Comment: I've posted my question just before you typed :)

Comment: Ok. Well it is good to accept prior questions when answered before posting new. If you leave a trail of unaccepted answers it leaves people, or certainly me, less inclined to answer.

Comment: @Atomix Well use `= Selection.Address` instead. I recommend to read some tutorials about the VBA basics.